# Centralized Application properties for multiple system

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am looking for a open-source solutions which allow hosting different properties for different applications and allow changes. On any change of properties it should notify or push the change to the application appropriately.

So, instead every application managing the properties in physical file and deploying physically; these properties can be pushed to a single system. User will have GUI to load and change the properties as per right.  Should allow push as mentioned.

If you have already similar open source solutions in mind please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that Puppet can manage for you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you've described (as nice as it would be) will be likely to exist in an app server. If a program is looking for a file, it's either going to load it with a FileReader (or similar), or it will use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(). It might be looking for data that is returned in properties, format, XML properties format, or even something completely different like RDF with which to configure itself. Also many programs read their config on start-up and then hold the values in memory, so you would still need to reboot them to get them to change.

To get something like this to work there would need to be a standard for configuration provisioning and live updates. Once that existed the webapp authors and server vendors would each need to add support for the standard.

If you are the one writing the programs to be managed however, then you can write your programs to request configuration from a service, and have a configuration push feature.... there may be packages out there that can speed up adding that to your code, but I get the impression you are looking to manage programs written by others.

Comment: yes, with little more features like

- Every application that wants to use these services will have a option of local store.

- Local Store will be in sync with the server/remote store and is managed with push mechanism with the help of the client agent.

- Easy configurable to any time of technology/application (Java, JEE, Dot.Net)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use JMX? I think he could be a good starting point to implement your requirements.

MBeans's attributes can store your application's properties, the MBeanServer will allow you to make them available from remotting, JConsole offers you an GUI to update properties values.

You also can write within the MBean some code that notify the corrrespondig application when a user change any properties using the GUI.